# NachOS timer.cc constructor

Tags: c++, timer, nachos

I am trying to create a new class in NachOS called alarmclock. In it, I need to create a timer object to use to trigger interrupts. In `timer.cc`, the constructor is

```
Timer::Timer(VoidFunctionPtr timerHandler, int callArg, bool doRandom)
```

Can someone please explain to me what inputs this constructor will take, and what `VoidFunctionPtr timerHandler` is and how it works? I have absolutely no idea what arguments to pass to this function so I'm just stuck here unable to do anything so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know it is a pointer to a function, but I do not understand how it works.

Comment: Seems like a pointer to a `void` function. Pass it a void function. If that gives you an error, fix it appropriately.

Comment: You should add your own answer! It could help somebody in the future.

Comment: timeHandler is basically a pointer to the function we want to execute using the timer. callArg is the input to that function and doRandom is a Boolean for a random Time splicer that generates random interval alarms. It is used when we do not have or need a fixed interval timer

Comment: As an answer! You can accept it in two days. And we encourage that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

timeHandler is basically a pointer to the function we want to execute using the timer. callArg is the input to that function and doRandom is a Boolean for a random Time splicer that generates random interval alarms. It is used when we do not have or need a fixed interval timer